# Strange test termination in JetBrains GoLand

Tags: go, jetbrains-ide, goland

I am writing the following simple test (it tests a transaction in PostgreSQL)

```
t.Run("Case 2: Single Booking Twice - One Should fail", func(t *testing.T) {
    arg := AddToCalendarParams{
        RoomID: newRoom.ID,
        BookedIntervals: []pgtype.Range[pgtype.Timestamp]{
            {
                Lower: pgtype.Timestamp{
                    Time:             time.Date(3001, 1, 1, 9, 30, 0, 0, time.UTC),
                    InfinityModifier: 0,
                    Valid:            true,
                },
                Upper: pgtype.Timestamp{
                    Time:             time.Date(3001, 1, 1, 11, 30, 0, 0, time.UTC),
                    InfinityModifier: 0,
                    Valid:            true,
                },
                LowerType: pgtype.Exclusive,
                UpperType: pgtype.Exclusive,
                Valid:     true,
            },
        },
        FromOwner: false,
    }

    errorChannel := make(chan error)
    defer close(errorChannel)

    go func() {
        err := store.CreateBookingsTx(context.Background(), arg)
        errorChannel <- err
    }()

    go func() {
        err := store.CreateBookingsTx(context.Background(), arg)
        errorChannel <- err
    }()

    err := <-errorChannel // the first error should be nil
    require.NoError(t, err)
    err = <-errorChannel // the second error should be not nil
    require.Error(t, err)
    //fmt.Printf("Error: %v", err)
})
```

When i remove the comment from the last line, the test does not terminate (no errors, the test are just marked as stopped).
With the comment, there is not problem and the tests terminate normally.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Do you get the same results when running via `go test`? It's hard to answer without more info; the `Printf` will call `err.Error()` so the issue may within that function.

Comment: "go test" completes fine (no errors, exit code 0). This also happens inside JetBrains, but the test is not marked as passed.

I split the printf statement in two, one with `s:= err.Error()` and then printing the result. I have the same problem.

Replacing the s with an underscore and removing the print command, shows the test as completed.

Comment: Similar issues have been [reported in the past](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-7855/Tests-arent-considered-as-passed-if-there-was-a-std-output) ([also](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-12226/Running-gocheck-test-shows-no-tests-were-run-instead-of-passing-them)) and it seems may not have been fully solved. Probably best to add your info on youtrack.